# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

```
links = ['https://www.cnnindonesia.com/tv/20211101202542-407-715220/video-20-november-tiongkok-vaksinasi-anak-usia-3-11-tahun', 
        'https://www.cnnindonesia.com/nasional/20211101192825-32-715200/demokrat-sindir-menteri-jokowi-jadi-marketing-bisnis-pcr', 
        'https://www.cnnindonesia.com/nasional/20211101210153-25-715231/indonesia-distribusikan-2355-juta-dosis-vaksin-sepanjang-2021']
            
titles = []
news_content = []
dates = []
    
    for link in links:
        response = requests.get(link)
        soup_link = bs(response.text, 'lxml')
        cont_dtl = soup_link.find_all('div', class_='content_detail')
        for cont in cont_dtl:
            news_title = cont.find('h1', class_='title').text.strip()
            titles.append(news_title)
            date_upload = cont.find('div', class_='date').text.strip()
            dates.append(date_upload)
            find_p = cont.find_all('p')
            list_paragraphs = []
            for p in range(len(find_p)):
                paragraph = find_p[p].get_text()
                list_paragraphs.append(paragraph)
                final_text = " ".join(list_paragraphs)
            news_content.append(final_text)
```

when i tried change to css select method it was still result same output = AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in which line you get "AttributeError: 'NoneType'" But sometimes bs4 receives None if there is more div or you are looking for something that has no text inside or simply didn't find div/h1 with this class. Check if every div,h1 has text inside and has a class you mentioned. I personally do it like that(I add it to every "find" where I have a problem with None Type):

```
if cont.find('div', class_='date') == None: 
    pass
else:
    date_upload = cont.find('div', class_='date').text.strip()
```

It is interesting that your code works fine in my python :D But try this what I said

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the other, it is working and there is no error thrown. To avoid such errors in case there no `element` were you can get text from just check like:

```
title = cont.h1.get_text(strip=True) if cont.h1 else 'no title'
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

data = []

links = ['https://www.cnnindonesia.com/tv/20211101202542-407-715220/video-20-november-tiongkok-vaksinasi-anak-usia-3-11-tahun', 
        'https://www.cnnindonesia.com/nasional/20211101192825-32-715200/demokrat-sindir-menteri-jokowi-jadi-marketing-bisnis-pcr', 
        'https://www.cnnindonesia.com/nasional/20211101210153-25-715231/indonesia-distribusikan-2355-juta-dosis-vaksin-sepanjang-2021']

for link in links:
    url = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'lxml')
    cont = soup.find('div', class_='content_detail')
    title = cont.h1.get_text(strip=True) if cont.h1 else 'no title'
    date = cont.find('div', class_='date').text.strip() if cont.find('div', class_='date') else 'no date'
    content = ' '.join([p.get_text(strip=True) for p in cont.select('p')]) if cont.p else 'no content'


    data.append({
        'title':title,
        'date':date,
        'content':content
    })    

        
data
```

Hint: Dont deal with this separate lists, use dicts.